# TFS 2017 Build - Customize the "agent_builddirectory" name

Tags: build, tfsbuild

in TFS 2017.2 the agent_builddirectory is a consecutive number. I would like to change it to be the Build Definition Name.

How can I achieve that?

Regards!

Comment: You can't. What problem are you encountering that makes this an issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Daniel! I think it is counter efficient the way it is. I hafve the builds under D:\Builds. When I want to see one specific build, I have to open one by one the folders with numbers D:\Builds\1, D:\Builds\2, D:\Builds\X until I find  what folder has my build definition. Does that make sense? @DanielMann

Comment: Why do you need to go into these folders in the first place? If you're troubleshooting a failing build, the build log will contain the full path to the agent's working folder at many points. If you're doing something else, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I see your point, but, just like with everything else, we have our reasons. If you recall the XAML based builds allowed you to customize the build directory. BTW: saying "you are doing something wrong" with so much little context is very irresponsible as you are judging and concluding based on nothing. I might be doing things different, yes, whether it is wrong or not depends on our specific needs. Regards!

Comment: What reasons? I'm asking so that I can provide guidance on solving the root problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot customize the “agent_builddirectory” name, unless you reconfigure the agent to change the work folder (create a folder and set the build definition name as the folder name ) before trigger build with the specific build definition.

The alternative way would be create a source folder with the specific build definition name as the folder name on the agent machine.

For example "`C:\BuildDefinitionName1`" and then add a "`Copy Files`" task in your build definition to copy the source code from "$(build.sourcesdirectory)" to "`C:\BuildDefinitionName1`". And then update the settings for other task to run build/test from "`C:\BuildDefinitionName1`" folder. Make sure to check the "`Overwrite`" option for "Copy Files" task.

Reference this similar thread: [TFS 2015 Build: How to change Agent.BuildDirectory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/112f2b4e-abac-420c-876c-24c86546bf51/tfs-2015-build-how-to-change-agentbuilddirectory?forum=tfsgeneral)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to the build the do it by itself, but certainly your answer would do the trick. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Most steps of a build execution (e.g. get sources, test assemblies, publish result) are somehow logging their working folder.

By looking at the results of a previously run build you will find out the folder you are looking for.